# Pass value from one input to another on button click

Tags: jquery

I have 3 elements:

- input1
- input2
- button

My aim is to pass value from input 1 to input 2 on button click.

My code is:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#input1").keyup(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("#input2").val(value);
        });
    });
```

But this works when user types.
I need to pass value from input1 to input 2 not when user types, but when user clicks button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `keyup` event on the input. Use the `click` event on the button. Instead of using `this` to get the value, you can simply get the value of the first input with the id.

Here's an example with some html:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aButton").click(function() {
    var value = $("#input1").val();
    $("#input2").val(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" />
<input id="input2" />
<button id="aButton">Button</button>
```